# Updating in bookshelf js using username

Tags: postgresql, express, bookshelf.js

I am trying to update a table using bookshelf js. But the it requires a id to update the table. I want to update the refresh token whenever a user logs in but how can i get the id in the database.

```
await new User({ username: user.username }).save({ refreshToken }, { method: 'update' });
```

this command works only when i pass in the id instead of username. Is there any way i can solve this?

Comment: How are you logging in without getting the `id` of the user?

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to provide id to update table data. You can try in this way with username.

```
const username = req.body.username;
const refreshToken = req.body.refreshToken;

User.forge({ username: username })
.fetch({ require: true })
.then((user) => user.save({ refreshToken : refreshToken }))
.catch((error) => return res.json({message: error.message}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your username column has a unique constraint.

Have you tried getting the user first by username and then perform an update?

I have a similar use case and solved this way:

```
User.forge({ username })
.fetch({ require: true })
.then((user) => user.save({ refreshToken }))
```